# How to get a masked rgba array from a ScalarMappable object

Tags: python, matplotlib

The docs for `to_rgba` state:

> Note: this method assumes the input is well-behaved; it does not check
>   for anomalies such as x being a masked rgba array, or being an integer
>   type other than uint8, or being a floating point rgba array with
>   values outside the 0-1 range.

But that's exactly what I need: a masked rgba array. The following was adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140072/how-to-map-number-to-color-using-matplotlibs-colormap) and gives me the correct values, except the values that are `nan` (that I make zero on the first line) should be black rgba values in `spc_map_color`

```
spc_map[np.isnan(spc_map)] = 0
gradient_range = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(-1.0, 1.0)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(
  gradient_range, self.cm_type)
spc_map_color = cmap.to_rgba(spc_map, bytes=True)
```

So as you can see, the colourmap used is variable, but the rgba value that is returned for values outside the mask (that are `nan`) should be invariant, i.e. always black.

Answers for how to do this for `linearsegmentedcolourmap` objects exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718101/applying-different-color-map-to-mask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548813/python-color-map-but-with-all-zero-values-mapped-to-black). But this is done if you want to output the image with `imshow`. I don't want to do that. I want the rgba values in an array.

I've tried `cmap.set_bad(color='black')` for instance with cmap as my `ScalarMappable` above before converting to rgba, but `ScalarMappable` doesn't have a `set_bad` function.

I missed something obvious?

You can use
`spc_map = np.random.randn(256,256)` and then do something like set all values below some value to zero to test solutions you may have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black typically corresponds to [0, 0, 0, 1] in an RGBA array. So just set all masked positions to these values ex post.

```
# get mask of masked array
mask = spc_map.mask 

# RGBA array should have one more dimension than spc_map with length 4 
spc_map_color[mask] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```